# How do i remove extra spaces while printing two string variables in java

Tags: java, string

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = scan.nextInt();
        for ( int i=0; i<T ; i++)
        {
            String str = scan.next();

            int even =0 , odd =0, len = str.length();
            String str1=null, str2=null;

            char [] str_even = new char[50];
            char [] str_odd = new char[50];

            for ( int j=0 ; j<len ; j ++)
            {
                if ( j %2 ==0)
                {
                    str_even[even] = str.charAt(j);
                    even++ ;
             str1 = String.valueOf(str_even);
                }

                if (j%2!=0)
                {
                    str_odd[odd] = str.charAt(j);
                    odd++ ;
                    str2 = String.valueOf(str_odd);
                }
            }
           String output = str1+str2 ;
            System.out.print(output);

        }

        scan.close();
    }
```

if inputstring is

```
Hacker
Rank
```

Expected output :

```
Hce akr
Rn ak
```

My Output:

```
Hce                          akr
                    Rn
a
```

Comment: you can use `trim` for string

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are converting the entire fixed length `char[]` into a `String`, but you only want the a portion of it. Fortunately there is a three-arg overload of `String.valueOf` that combines a `substring`.

```
str1 = String.valueOf(str_even, 0, even);
```

It lookes like you will also need to add a separator space back into the output.

(Not that there aren't other general issues with the code.)

Comment: Thanks .It helped me :)

Comment: In this regard, why don't you use two Strings `even` and `odd` instead of a char array?

Comment: @GameDroids Without making many changes, the `char[]` approach can be transformed from O(n^2) to O(n). Could also use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You are right, *Mea culpa* - the String-idea was a bad idea. Strings shouldn't be used like that. I just thought it would be more intuitive than `char[]`. In this case the `StringBuilder` should do just fine. Easy enough to use and not as bad performing as `String`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove spaces there are many options.

```
// Remove spaces , tabs and returns
System.out.println(text.replaceAll("\\s",""));

// Remove spaces in the beginning and at the end
System.out.println(text.trim());
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks . It helped :)

Comment: Your welcome, btw dont forget to mark someone answer. Tom´s seems more helpful in this case.

Comment: The extra characters appear to be NUL characters, so I don't think this will work in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

First, your arrays are of the wrong size. Use this:

```
        char [] str_even = new char[(len+1)/2];
        char [] str_odd = new char[len/2];
```

second, you don't need to create `str1` and `str2` at each iteration. Create them after the loop.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me :)